# Confusion about finding V given U and S during SVD

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

I understand any rectangular mxn matrix A is a factorization of the form:
$$ A = U\Sigma V^{\top}$$
where U and V are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is diagonal.
Say, I have found U and $\Sigma$ and looking for V.
$$
A = U\Sigma V^{\top} \\ 
AV = U\Sigma \\ 
Av_i = \sigma_i u_i \\ 
A^{\top}Av_i = A^{\top}\sigma_i u_i \\ 
v_i = A^{\top}\sigma_i u_i \\ 
v_i = \sigma_iA^{\top}u_i \\ 
$$
Also from my notes I have,
$$
A = U\Sigma V^{\top} \\ 
A^{\top}A = A^{\top}U\Sigma V^{\top} \\ 
I = A^{\top}U\Sigma V^{\top} \\
A^{\top}U = V\Sigma^{\top} \\
(A^{\top}U)_i = v_i\sigma_i \\
v_i = \frac{(A^{\top}U)_i}{\sigma_i}
$$

What am I doing wrong to get these conflicting equations?

Comment: You seem to have confused $X^\top$ (the transpose of $X$) with $X^{-1}$ (the inverse of $X$) in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks, where do I do that?

Comment: In the first group of equations, you seem to assume that $A^\top A=I$ when going from the fourth to the fifth equation. In the second group, this occurs in the transition between the second and the third equations.

Comment: Oh so the first group of equations is true only if A is an orthogonal matrix. So taking the case where A is an orthogonal matrix, are these two equations correct?

Comment: Yes. If $A$ is orthogonal, then $\Sigma=I$.